# How to get BluetoothDevice object by Intent's putExtra on Android?

Tags: android, android-intent, casting

I was trying to send BluetoothDevice object by intent.
There is no problem when attach BluetoothDevice object with putExtra, but there is problem if I tried to get BluetoothDevice by getIntent.

Here is details of problem and codes

`MainActivity`

```
BluetoothDevice btDevice = deviceAdapter.getBleDevice(i);
           Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),bleDeviceControlActivity.class);
           intent.putExtra("btDevice",btDevice);
           startActivity(intent);
```

`NextActivity`

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_ble_device_control);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        btDevice = intent.getSerializableExtra("btDevice");

    }
```

the problem occurs on this code
`btDevice = intent.getSerializableExtra("btDevice");`

Required type is BluetoothDevice  but provided type is Serializable.
I tried to cast with

`btDevice = (BluetoothDevice) intent.getSerializableExtra("btDevice");`

but this code still doesn't work.

Comment: `doesn't work` means nothing really.

Answer (score 1):

`BluetoothDevice` implements `Parcelable`. You should use `getParcelableExtra()` instead of `getSerializableExtra()`.